# ExecuteUpdate() hangs and not able to run my program

Tags: jdbc, netbeans-8

I am trying JDBC to run this code as a servlet for my .JSP file in netbeans with derby database. My problem doesn't run beyond "stmt.addBatch(query);" It doens't print "hello". I have also used derby.jar,derbyclient.jar and derbynet.jar in library.

Looking forward to hear from others.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; 
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.sql.*;


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Reg</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String rate=request.getParameter("Rate");
        out.println(name);
        out.println(rate);
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample","APP","");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        String query="insert into movie values('"+rate+"','" +name+ "')";

        stmt.addBatch(query);
        out.println("hello");

        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look for a stack trace in your server console / logs. And learn about prepared statements if you want to avoid SQL injection attacks, and be able to insert a name containing a quote.

Comment: So i should prepared statement instead of create statement?

Comment: same issue couldn't found solution